# YouTube URL parameters issue. YouTube not using HTTP ranges

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to understand all the parameters of a YouTube video as YouTube is now not using the HTTP range element but using its own range parameters inside its URL and thus I am not able to make a session using the Wireshark as i see so many HTTP 200 ok with video/x-flv and thus my player is not able to associate them as it reads the HTTP responses and its ranges.  Here are the sample URLs what YouTube is sending for a single video. Is there any documetation available for this as well?

GET /videoplayback?algorithm=throttle-factor&burst=40&cp=U0hTTldOVF9FUUNOM19PSFhIOnBNNjJuUGVsZDZU&expire=1349736707&factor=1.25&fexp=922401%2C920704%2C912806%2C900711%2C913546%2C913556%2C925109%2C919003%2C920201%2C912706%2C900816&id=ee88421fc6a3f768&ip=90.84.144.49&ipbits=8&itag=34&keepalive=yes&key=yt1&ms=au&mt=1349713452&mv=m&newshard=yes&***range=13-1781759***&signature=84690C3B43F6FFBDD69E0E7009D0A6436946D642.904ADA59891696B5D1411665853784438D9E35D4&source=youtube&sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&sver=3&upn=fc55lw1im0s HTTP/1.1

GET /videoplayback?algorithm=throttle-factor&burst=40&cp=U0hTTldOVF9FUUNOM19PSFhIOnBNNjJuUGVsZDZU&expire=1349736707&factor=1.25&fexp=922401%2C920704%2C912806%2C900711%2C913546%2C913556%2C925109%2C919003%2C920201%2C912706%2C900816&id=ee88421fc6a3f768&ip=90.84.144.49&ipbits=8&itag=34&keepalive=yes&key=yt1&ms=au&mt=1349713563&mv=m&newshard=yes&***range=10690560-12472319***&signature=84690C3B43F6FFBDD69E0E7009D0A6436946D642.904ADA59891696B5D1411665853784438D9E35D4&source=youtube&sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&sver=3&upn=fc55lw1im0s&redirect_counter=1&cms_redirect=yes HTTP/1.1

GET /videoplayback?algorithm=throttle-factor&burst=40&cp=U0hTTldOVF9FUUNOM19PSFhIOnBNNjJuUGVsZDZU&expire=1349736707&factor=1.25&fexp=922401%2C920704%2C912806%2C900711%2C913546%2C913556%2C925109%2C919003%2C920201%2C912706%2C900816&id=ee88421fc6a3f768&ip=90.84.144.49&ipbits=8&itag=34&keepalive=yes&key=yt1&ms=au&mt=1349713452&mv=m&newshard=yes&***range=12472320-14254079***&signature=84690C3B43F6FFBDD69E0E7009D0A6436946D642.904ADA59891696B5D1411665853784438D9E35D4&source=youtube&sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&sver=3&upn=fc55lw1im0s HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 1):

For your question, see this [thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20200324061248/http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/anyone-knows-some-info-about-youtube-quot-range-quot-parameter-td4584388.html).

Youtube streaming works providing 1.7MB chunk pieces controlled by range param, which indicate [start byte]-[end byte].

I'am also questioning similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365272/is-begin-param-dead-in-youtubes-c-youtube-com-videoplayback).

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation for this sort of thing, and video streams are generally considered a "black box" from a developer's perspective.

Comment: Yeah, i have searched and there is noting but i have found bits of the information and i am able to understand to some extent the URLs but the issue is i can see those 1.7MB chunks using Wireshark and i want to play them in my player but for that i need to merge them and i am not finding any way to do so. The chunks are coming on different IPs and ports and also coming with the ranges but some of the chunks doesnt seems seems to be inline with the previous chunks and thus its not making a proper flv file. NAy idea on this?